# Template hook is not being triggered in custom Nikola theme

Tags: python, mako, nikola

I am trying to write a custom theme for Nikola, a static site generator. I have been mostly following [their tutorial](https://getnikola.com/creating-a-theme.html) but have run into a problem. I want to show certain HTML specifically on pages (not on posts) in the spot where the `page_header` template hook appears. So I first ran this command:

```
nikola theme -c page.tmpl
```

That copies the base theme's page.tmpl file into my custom theme's directory. That file is actually only 1 line long, simply this:

```
<%inherit file="story.tmpl"/>
```

So I added a definition for `<%block name="page_header"> ... </%block>`. However, the code I defined inside that block does not show up on my pages. Just to make sure I wasn't going crazy, I also defined `<%block name="extra_head"> ... </%block>` within that same page.tmpl file, and in that case the code contained therein *did* show up.

Why would the overridden `extra_head` block work while the overridden `page_header` block doesn't work within the same template file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having an issue where the overridden `page_header` block is not showing up but the `extra_head` block is, then it is possible that the `page_header` hook is not being used or triggered in the parent template (`story.tmpl`) that `page.tmpl` is inheriting from.

See [`zzzeek/mako` / `doc/build/inheritance.rst`](https://github.com/zzzeek/mako/blob/272f5d8cc97aee829e3b285486f33c9c8e604c74/doc/build/inheritance.rst)

> Using template inheritance, two or more templates can organize themselves into an **inheritance chain**, where content and functions from all involved templates can be intermixed.
> The general paradigm of template inheritance is this:
>
> if a template `A` inherits from template `B`, then template `A` agrees to send the executional control to template `B` at runtime (`A` is called the **inheriting** template).
> Template `B`, the **inherited** template, then makes decisions as to what resources from `A` shall be executed.

To check that, make sure that `story.tmpl` or any other template that it may inherit from actually uses the `page_header` block. If it does not exist there, then overriding it in `page.tmpl` will not have any effect.

Sometimes, there might be multiple layers of template inheritance. Do make sure there is no intermediate template between `page.tmpl` and `story.tmpl` that might be interfering with the blocks.

As a test, try to explicitly invoke the `page_header` block within `page.tmpl` outside of the block definition, like:

`mako ${self.page_header()}`

That should force the rendering of the content of that block, if it is correctly defined.